# Get serialised size of List without having OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, out-of-memory

Ok just to be clear, I'm aware about all the LOH thing and the big object (more than 85k) and the big list (more 40k elements) that gets into the LOH.

So my problem is, **I need to know the size of a List when serialised using a XMLSerialiser** (I don't care about the space it takes in the RAM or anything like that, I just want its size when serialized) but if I try to **serialise a big list containing big elements I get the OutOfMemoryException** (And I know why)

What I want to know is : Is it possible to serialise a List **Element by Element** and cumulate the size of it in a loop like : 
    //This will be pseudo code

```
long byteLength = 0;
using(stream)
{
  foreach(element in MyList)
  {
    MemoryStream.Serialise(element);
    byteLength += MemoryStream.Length;

    MemoryStream.Clear();
  }
}
```

Any Suggestion ?

---

UPDATE : 
Solution by @xanatos do what I want to do because it doesn't add in the ram a big byte[] that will be stored in the LOH

As @Hans Passant said, it seems like the purpose of WHY I want to do this treatment is important so : I want to know the size in byte of a List serialised in XML to be able to split the list in multiple file on disk according to its total byte.

Comment: Yep but it seem like even if I serialise objects in my stream, the length and the position doesn't seems to have the good values... I cumulated the `MemoryStream.Length` and was reseting the `Position` to 0 with the `Seek(0,0)` function

Comment: You have to be pretty desperate to write code like this, surely there's a better approach.  Starting with just a few objects and get an estimate by multiplying with the list's Count.  Pretty unclear what problem you are *really* trying to solve, large serialized data fits pretty well on a disk instead of memory.

Comment: I think my problem is clear, the context is unclear because it is not necessary. My problem : I want to serialise a List<T> without having all it's byte serialised in my LOH. The solution that @xanatos submited fix it because it does not create a big `byte[]` but only get the `Length` of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you need is only the length:

```
class NulStream : Stream
{
    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false;  }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
    }

    protected long length;

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return this.length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return this.length;
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        this.length += count;
    }
}

using (var nul = new NulStream())
{
    xml.Serialize(nul, lst);
    long length = nul.Length;
}
```

It is a NUL stream... like the NUL file :-) It will eat what you throw at it, and save only the cumulative length.

Note that technically I could have implemented the `SetLength`, and `Write` should check its parameters... But why? :-)

Comment: With this method it won't store the serialise byte in the LOH ? Because it's the original problem

Comment: @Tareck117 No, it won't. Because the `XmlSerializer` sends to the stream a piece at a time, 1024-2048 bytes from some experiments. If you want to see it, add this line in the override void Write(...): Console.WriteLine(count);